# Htaccess Route Redirect for Next JS Static Build

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, next.js

I want to redirect static files of next js with htaccess. For example:

[image: 1]

How can I redirect young-talent to young-talent.html

I try this:

```
RewriteRule ^young-talent$ /young-talent.html [L,R=301]
```

it's working but I couldn't delete .html extension and secondly I don't know How I can redirect to young-talent -> [detail].

is there example this?

Comment: Remove the `R=301` flag. It's used for external URL redirection and changes the URL in browser .

Comment: @AmitVerma That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.